# How to setup RStudio Desktop verion on a CentOS 5 machine?

Tags: centos

I have a problem of install RStudio Desktop verion on a CentOS 5 machine. Basically, RStudio Desktop needs QT4.8; however, I am not sure how to update my CentOS 5 QT4 to QT4.8. Otherwise, the Cmake can't go through.

Comment: Another partial workaround is running R for Windows under WINE, although in one of the setups I had to use GUIs that were much worse than RStudio (in terms of user friendliness). Other than that, we use CentOS 6.4 and have no problems with RStudio. Generally, rolling out a clean workstation with CentOS 6 is much much better than sticking to 5.9 ('tis different with servers, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your reply; however, if I ask our IT department to update my desktop to CentOS 6.4, will it affect all the packages, software that I have already installed on my CentOS 5 system? Or should I re-install all the software? If so, then that cost too much... But anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use self-contained Zip/Tarball from http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/desktop? You don't have to install it, just download it, unpack it and go to bin folder and run rstudio. It looks like you need to have R installed, but QT libraries are included.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. That was what exactly I tried before as well. However, I got the error message:

> rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I am not sure where I can find this libgio-2.0.so.0 by googling it online :-(

Comment: Tried to installed glib glib2 but still can't find this libgio-2.0.so.0

Comment: I haven't used CentOS, but in openSUSE, libgio-2.0.so.0 comes with libgio-2_0-0 package, not glib. Please try to find and install libgio-2_0-0 or libgio*.

Comment: No libgio for CentOS... shamed. I have no idea why research institutions always prefer to setup CentOS, which is a bad system overall compared to SUSE, Ubuntu...

Comment: Too bad, I did find a thread about it https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=24870 but I'm afraid I cannot give you any more help. Hope you get it working somehow!